# Где в исходниках Android находится код, отвечающий за запрос разрешений у пользователя во время выполнения?

Tags: android, android-permissions

На встроенном устройстве без экрана пользователь не видит что приложению требуется разрешение на выполнение каких-то действий. Хорошо бы изменить код операционной системы чтобы приложение всегда получала одобрение своих действий без участия пользователя. Помогите найти этот кусок кода в Android. Больше всего интересует версия Android 7.1.2 для модуля Quectel SC20.

Вы можете возразить что приложение нужно сделать системным и ему будет всё можно, но каждый раз собирать систему и загружать её в модуль это ад по сравнению с отладкой в Android Studio.

Ещё аргумент, в проекте участвуют мои коллеги, занимающиеся прикладной частью задачи, которые умеют отлаживать Android Studio но не могут Linux совсем. Замечу что коллеги не молоды...

> Немного расскажу как у меня устроено...
>
> Сборка Android выполняется в виртуальной машине через консоль, я так настроил специально чтобы можно было собрать OS не перегружая компьютер. Linux установлен на отдельный HDD и его можно запустить и обычным способом, но мне жутко не привычно и не удобно работать в среде Linux. К тому же у меня есть другая работа которую я делаю в Win10. Файлы образа OS после сборки я перекидываю в Windows и из неё зашиваю в модуль.

Совершенно не представляю как можно разработать и отладить **системное приложение** при таком трудоёмком способе внесения изменений. Если есть способы/предложения как облегчить разработку и отладку системного приложения то я весь внимание.

Хочу обратить внимание на тот момент что, отладка в эмуляторе не подойдёт, приложение использует внешнее оборудование подключенное к модулю для получения данных которые обрабатывает.

Столкнулся с ещё такой трудностью, как переделать проект из Android Studio 3.XX в AOSP? [похожий вопрос давно задан но ответа нет](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49874401/convert-gradle-file-to-mk-file-build-gradle-to-android-mk)

---

> Есть такая особенность, когда вставляешь USB-serisl в телефон с запущенной программой, которая использует его, всплывает запрос разрешения на доступ к USB

2020/02/05 **Нашёл способ для Android 7.1.2**
Теперь на запрос доступа к USB всегда положительный ответ.
Окно запроса даже не появляется.

Для этого добавил только одну функцию в файл и пере-собрал систему:
`/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/usb/UsbPermissionActivity.java`

```java
    // хак системы, на запрос доступа к USB всегда положительный ответ
    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        mPermissionGranted = true;
        Log.e(TAG, "auto enable USB permission (ikpyt)");
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: Откройте и посмотрите. В чём проблема-то? О_о

Comment: Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica - проблема в том что-бы найти. Mне не хватает знаний об устройстве Android чтобы найти самостоятельно. А  с Linux мне тяжко, мелкие правки и собрать Android получается но трассировать систему я пока не умею. Собственно найти проблема. Может кто находил уже или знает как это устроено в Android, в каком месте копать?
Исходники тут:
`repo init -u https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la/platform/manifest.git -b release -m LA.BR.1.2.9-04610-8x09.0.xml --repo-url=git://codeaurora.org/tools/repo.git --repo-branch=caf-stable`

Comment: Про какой код речь тогда? Запросы на пермишены вы сами из кода отправляете...

Comment: Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica - Изменил формулировку вопроса, надеюсь что мне удалось его правильно задать.

Comment: *отвечающий за **проверку*** - так мне кажется будет ближе к теме. Я бы начал поиск с `PackageManager` или методов запроса/проверки, которые мы должны вызывать для получения разрешений. Но вместо модификации системы не проще само приложение сделать системным? Предустановленные приложения ведь не запрашивают у вас никаких разрешений, а имеют доступ ко всему.

Comment: woesss - Вы говорите `PackageManager` - возможно. Я уже пытался найти и буду продолжать поиск, но всё-же надеюсь что кто-то другой обладает знаниями, позволяющими решить эту задачу или уже решал подобную. 

Добавил информации в основной вопрос об обстоятельствах его вызвавших.

**woesss** - спасибо вам за желание помочь!